# Custom routing with Three20 TTURLMap

Tags: iphone, three20

I would like to have different routing rule for my application:
* standard URL (http/https)
* custom URL : myApp://user
* custom URL 2 : myApp://message

In each case, I need to call a different controller.

For the moment, I added a TTURL Map in the Delegate of my application:

```
[map from:@"http://*" toViewController:[BrowserController class]];
[map from:@"https://*" toViewController:[BrowserController class]];
[map from:@"myApp://user/*" toViewController:[TTWebController class]];
```

and I have such text in my TTStyledTextLabel:

```
[TTStyledText textFromXHTML:@"<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">link</a> from <a href=\"myApp://user/bob\">bob</a>"];
```

However, there is no action triggered when I click on one of the link.
How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Two resources for you: http://three20.stackexchange.com/ and http://www.three20.info/ui/navigation  ...My guess is that you need the `tt://` line, but I haven't dug through his code enough to verify that as true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use the wildcard in `myApp://user/*`. You should review the demo code for TTNavigator if you want to do custom initialization for parameters (such as "bob").